# How to use Yandex Map by Vaadin UI Framework?

Tags: java, javascript, dictionary, vaadin, yandex-api

i want to use Vaadin framework to my application, I need a map. I can not use Google Map because it doesn't describe my city well, but yandex maps do. In API i read that it seems easy with html:

...

...

Then prepare div container:

How i can use by Vaadin? Please, somebody help.

Comment: html: <head>
...
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/index.xml?key=API-ключ" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
</head>

Comment: <div id="YMapsID" style="width:600px;height:400px"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must implement your own CustomWidget that will insert Yandex's javascript, here good [example](http://juravskiy.ru/?p=8), you can use xml for same aim. Then will implement all manipulations on client side by gwt, connect it with server side.

Comment: is the link broken?